# Displaying different label text each second

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, timer, label

I have three forms, From 1 is a main form and Form2 is splash screen and Form3 is a mini form.
So what i am trying to do is when ever i send a mail this From3 will pop up which has a gif image
and a label. So i am successfully able to make the From3 for 5 sec, in which the label will
change for different `words` for each second.

In form 3
i am using timer1 to run the mini form only for 5 seconds. and timer two to run only for 1 sec.

**I guess we can do this in a better way** which is pretty simple and easy.. Any good ideas and
help are most welcome!!!

Note:- Also when i again press the button send mail.. the label is starting from - `Done!!`.. Any helps.. The first time it starts from `Connecting to smtp server..`but on second time onwards its staring from `Done!!` then label going to `Connecting to smtp server..` and so on!!
Here is my code:

Form1

```
 private void sendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //mail basic function here!!!!
     smtp.Send(msg);
     _f3.ShowDialog();//- - ->> goes to mini form Form3
     smtp.Dispose();
     MessageBox.Show("Email Successfully Sent!!!", "Mail!!!.");
     }
```

Form3

```
 private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

    timer2.Interval = 1000;
    timer2.Start();
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    timer1.Stop();
}

int StopTime = 0;
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopTime++;
    if (StopTime == 1)
    {
        label1.Text = "  Connecting to smtp server..";
    }
    if (StopTime == 2)
    {
        label1.Text = "     Fetching recipients..";
    }
    if (StopTime == 3)
    {
        label1.Text = "  Attaching G-code files..";
    }
    if (StopTime == 4)
    {
        label1.Text = "                Done!!";
        StopTime = 0;
        timer2.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a code review of functional code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan please see the edited question. before the coding.. too thanks

Comment: @no i have an error... when i press the button again.. it is staring from `Done!!` label

Comment: If the spaces before your text is to achieve centering, it might be nicer to do this by setting AutoSize = false on the label, and TextAlign = MiddleCenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Form3 close after it displays Done? You could do something like this:

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetLabel1Text(); //reset label text
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

        timer2.Interval = 1000;
        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    int StopTime = 0;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopTime++;
        SetLabel1Text();
        if (StopTime == 4)
        {
            StopTime = 0;
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void SetLabel1Text()
    {
        string[] label1Text = { "  Connecting to smtp server..", "  Connecting to smtp server..", "     Fetching recipients..", "  Attaching G-code files..", "                Done!!" };
        label1.Text = label1Text[StopTime]; //populate label from array of values
    }
```

Comment: the form3 is closing. but i don't know wether its closing gracefully or not.. but in my case.. after 5 seconds.. that form closes and comes to main form

Comment: and where is timer1 .. u have not mentioned that

Comment: @please tell me wether i should give timer1 or not...can i do in both in timer2 or not.. please let me knoq

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote what I changed. Leave that part how you had it if it worked. I edited the answer to include it.

Comment: yes it worked..but is there some way.. other than timer.. is timer good.. by giving two timers in same mini form.. am i closing every thing correctly.. right!! i guess there won't be any memory leakage..

Comment: You could probably replace "if (StopTime == 4)" with "if (StopTime == 5)" and put the "this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK" inside of that if block. You wouldn't want to change the text on the label when the StopTime is 5 though.

Comment: That would allow you to use just one timer. There are other ways to do this, but a timer seems like an acceptable approach.